# How to CREATE a Temp table in SQL Server with a SEQUENCE PK Column

Tags: sql-server, sequence, temp-tables

I am able to create a table with a sequence, however when I attempt to use a sequence for a temp table, I get an error:

> Invalid object name '[sequence]'

Am I not able to add to a primary key using a sequence to a temp table? If I simply change `@tist` to `tist` making it a standard table it all works... problem is I need to make use of a temp table... not an actual table due to permissions.

```
    drop table if exists #tist
    drop table if exists #t_stg 

    drop sequence if exists i_seq
    go

    create sequence i_seq start with 1 increment by 1

    /* Error is this Line */
    create table #tist(id int primary key default (next value for dbo.i_seq), a int, b int)

    create table #t_stg(id int, a int, b int)

    insert into #t_stg(a,b) values (1,2),(3,3),(4,5)

    update #t_stg set id = next value for i_seq

    --select * from #t_stg

    insert into #tist(id,a,b) 
    select * from #t_stg 

    SELECT * FROM #tist
```

Comment: Here is a hint. In which database do you create your sequence? In which database is your temp table?

Comment: @SMor Interesting...so would I need to create my sequence in the tempdb database I suppose?  How would I do that?

Comment: Why you need to use `SEQUENCE` while you can use `IDENTITY(,1)`?

Comment: @Sami Well that's the big question... I started with using IDENTITY column and moved over to SEQUENCES as I was hoping it would fix my issue of pre-populating the IDs I have which I am eventually going to INSERT into my production environment... I posted this question in response to an answer I already received in another Post... The solution I thought was perfect however I can't use it with Temp Tables... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313315/how-to-add-a-set-of-keys-uniqueids-to-a-temp-table-to-later-insert-into-produc

Comment: Well crap... apparently I would need access to the tempdb in order to be able to create SEQUENCES for TEMP tables... Where is Oracle when you need it?  Perhaps I'm just still biased but Oracle things are so much easier lol.  Give me PACKAGES... give me robust looping structions... ARRAYS and COLLECTIONS are nice too.  Are the only OBJECTS we have available to use for manipulating data are TEMP TABLES.  Is that really it?

Comment: I went with a simple work around and simply decided to CREATE the TEMP TABLE without the sequence and then just update the temp table later... an extra step but not too bad.

Comment: You can also generate the sequence values on INSERT.  You can use 'next value for' on an INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or in a DEFAULT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like to get what I'm after I simply update the STAGING table with my sequence rather than attempting to CREATE my TEMP TABLE using the SEQUENCE.

```
DROP TABLE IF exists #t
DROP TABLE IF exists #t_stg 

DROP SEQUENCE IF exists dbo.t_seq

GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @Count INT = 981518;

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.t_seq START WITH 1 increment BY 1

SET @sql = N'ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.t_seq RESTART WITH ' + CAST(@Count AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ';';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
GO

CREATE TABLE #t(id INT, a INT, b INT)

CREATE TABLE #t_stg(id INT, a INT, b INT)

INSERT INTO #t_stg(a,b) VALUES (1,2),(3,3),(4,5)

--SELECT * FROM #t_stg

UPDATE #t_stg SET id = NEXT VALUE FOR t_seq

SELECT * FROM #t_stg

--INSERT INTO #t(id,a,b) 
--SELECT * FROM #t_stg

--SELECT * FROM #t

GO
```